# VSTO add in for multiple office application

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-office, vsto

I have created a VSTO addin using word 2010 template. I am using .net 4.0.
I am interested same functionality in excel 2010 and Power point 2010. Is it possible the add in, already developed could be reuse in excel and power point 2010.

i.e the same add in will work for word 2010, excel 2010 and Powerpoint 2010. I am giving least preferance to create three addins, one for word 2010, excel 2010 and Powerpoint 2010 as the functionality of all the addin is same.

Answer (score 1):

VSTO doesn't allow creating multihost add-ins. You can choose only one host per project in Visual Studio. Of course, you can create a single MSI installer for all your add-ins and deliver it as a single application. But you need to develop separate add-ins/projects in VS. Moreover, Office applications have different object models.

As an alternative way you may consider using Add-in Express which allows supporting multiple host applications in the single project.